# How To Execute Basic Json feeder using Scala Jackson Library in Idea IntelliJ Editor

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jackson, intellij-plugin

All i need to execute a basic Jackson library code using scala in Intellij Idea editor

I already have installed scala 
C:\Users\tt>scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.12.7 -- Copyright 2002-2018, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

import scala.collection.mutable

val input = scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.json").getLines()
val mapper = new ObjectMapper() with ScalaObjectMapper
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val obj = mapper.readValue[Map[String, Any]](input)
val data_collection = mutable.HashMap.empty[Int, String]
for (i <- c) {
data_collection.put(
obj.get("id").fold(0)(_.toString.toInt),
obj.get("text").fold("")(_.toString)
)
}
println(data_collection) // Map(1 -> Hello How are you)
```

I expect IntelliJ editor to automatcially suggest why ScalaObjectMapper and DefaultScalaModule showing as Cannot Resolve symbols despite of using correct imports

Getting errors like below

```
Error:(4, 1) expected class or object definition
                name := "jackson-module-scala"
                Error:(6, 1) expected class or object definition
                organization := "com.fasterxml.jackson.module"
                Error:(8, 1) expected class or object definition
                scalaVersion := "2.12.8"
                Error:(10, 1) expected class or object definition
                crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.7", "2.11.12", "2.12.8", 
                "2.13.0-M5")
                Error:(12, 1) expected class or object definition
                val scalaMajorVersion = SettingKey[Int]("scalaMajorVersion")
                Error:(13, 1) expected class or object definition
                scalaMajorVersion := {
                Error:(20, 1) expected class or object definition
                scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked", "-feature")
                Error:(27, 6) classes cannot be lazy
                lazy val java7Home =
                Error:(33, 1) expected class or object definition
                javacOptions ++= {
                Error:(41, 1) expected class or object definition
                scalacOptions ++= {
                Error:(45, 1) expected class or object definition
                unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile += {
                Error:(49, 1) expected class or object definition
                val jacksonVersion = "2.9.8"
                Error:(51, 1) expected class or object definition
                libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                Error:(65, 1) expected class or object definition
                resourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
                Error:(73, 1) expected class or object definition
                site.settings
                Error:(75, 1) expected class or object definition
                site.includeScaladoc()
                Error:(77, 1) expected class or object definition
                ghpages.settings
                Error:(79, 1) expected class or object definition
                git.remoteRepo := "git@github.com:FasterXML/jackson-module- 
                scala.git"
```